# Quintic Number Number Counting Hash Function

Tags: python, database, string, validation, formal-verification

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string hash = "248d6a61d20638b8e5c026930c3e6039a33ce45964ff2167f6ecedd419db06c1";

    std::cout << "SHA-256 hash in binary format: ";
    for (char c : hash) {
        switch (c) {
            case '0': std::cout << "0000"; break;
            case '1': std::cout << "0001"; break;
            case '2': std::cout << "0010"; break;
            case '3': std::cout << "0011"; break;
            case '4': std::cout << "0100"; break;
            case '5': std::cout << "0101"; break;
            case '6': std::cout << "0110"; break;
            case '7': std::cout << "0111"; break;
            case '8': std::cout << "1000"; break;
            case '9': std::cout << "1001"; break;
            case 'a': std::cout << "1010"; break;
            case 'b': std::cout << "1011"; break;
            case 'c': std::cout << "1100"; break;
            case 'd': std::cout << "1101"; break;
            case 'e': std::cout << "1110"; break;
            case 'f': std::cout << "1111"; break;
            default: std::cerr << "Invalid hex digit\n"; return 1; // Terminate the program if an invalid hex digit is encountered
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? And this doesn't look like python.